# Power Tile Effect: Initiative and Movement/Victory

Tags: kemet

When using the 'Initiative' power tile (which destroys two units pre-battle)  against a [foolish or unfortunate] opponent who has only two units:

Is a victory point scored?
Is movement interrupted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rulebook says:

> If the attacker wins the battle, and has at least one unit left, he gains a permanent Battle VP.

The English rulebook doesn't seem to be clear about the movements, but the German version clearly states that in the case of an Attack:

> The movement ends in every case.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get a victory point in this case:

-> The effect of 'Innitiative' resolves during Day-Phase. If you destroy the enemy troop during Day-Phase (Same as for example with a DI-card) there won't be a battle -> no VP.

Comment: Boggle.  I do not see how day phase relates to this circumstance.